# ASP.Net Core RC2 JWT Bearer token

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, bearer-token, .net-core-rc2

Does anyone have a complete example of using JWT bearer tokens with ASP.Net Core RC2 Identity? Preferably showing how to create the token also.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 2):

You may use [OpenIdDict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) - a simple implementation of [AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server).

[Here](https://github.com/capesean/openiddict-test) and [here](http://capesean.co.za/blog/asp-net-5-jwt-tokens/) is an example and article of using OpenIdDict.

[Here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/503) is a discussion in Identity repo about JWT token authentication in ASP.Core

> The official packages developed by Microsoft for ASP.NET Core only
>   support OAuth2 bearer token validation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm personnaly using IdentityServer4 in ASP.NET core RC2 as an authentication app using JWT Bearer token. (very good Samples available) https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4

For example : I have 3 projects (apps) in my solution

1. Login (IdentityServer4) that authenticate users and give them a JWT token when authenticated
2. API that is registered in IdentityServer4 as a consumer (Scope) for JWT tokens. Token attributes (Claims/Roles) are validated when accessing controller methods.
3. Web front end (Only HTML/AngularJS) that store the token and send it when sending a request (in the HTTP header) to the API. The front end is registered as "Client" in the Login

The big advantage to have an isolated Login app is that you can create as many API/front-end you want as long as you register them so they can communicate each other securely with the JWT token.

The samples available there https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples are very straigtforward.  If you have any question related to this project, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I've ASP.NET Core 1.1 as backend and angular as front end solution with JWT bearer tokens. tokens can be easily created by lib.

https://github.com/Longfld/ASPNETcoreAngularJWT

Answer (score 0):

I have a full example for ASP.NET Core with JWT auth: https://github.com/wilsonwu/netcoreauth

By the way, the database is SQL Server.